# Flutter Firebase (firebase_core) does not build on Android

Tags: firebase, flutter

When using the Firebase plugins and starting an Android build, I get the following error:

```
ERROR: Failed to resolve: com.google.firebase:firebase-core:
Affected Modules: app, firebase_core.
```

It works fine on iOS.

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
* What went wrong:
Could not determine the dependencies of task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
> Could not resolve all task dependencies for configuration ':app:debugCompileClasspath'.
   > Could not find com.google.firebase:firebase-core:.
     Required by:
         project :app
         project :app > project :firebase_core
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is an issue that occurs because FlutterFire is migrating to BoM.
To solve this issue for now, you should just use `firebase_core: 0.3.1+1`.

The [ideal solution](https://github.com/flutter/plugins/pull/1443) would be adding the following to your **`settings.gradle`** in your `android` module:

```
enableFeaturePreview('IMPROVED_POM_SUPPORT')
```

However, this might not work. In that case, you should revert to `0.3.1+1` for the moment.

You can find out more about it [here](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/30606).

Comment: You save my day. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 3):

This issue was fixed in the 0.3.4 update of firebase_core, which is a dependency of other Flutter Firebase plugins. You should be able to get the fix with a "flutter packages upgrade".

https://github.com/flutter/plugins/pull/1464/files